# Better hit detection for Triangle shaped button (libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx

my title might not be very clear (wasn't sure how to explain it) but I've been working on a game interface trying to find the best way to have good hit detection for my walking buttons. This is what the end result should look like:

[image: 4 buttons]

The first way I tried was to separate each triangle on it's own and just use Buttons for each but the problem that I come to with this is that an image needs to be inside of a rectangle shape and so there's an overlap between the 4 buttons and moving left might trigger the up button so I decided to try something else.

The second way was to just put the whole image as one button and then manually set the y and x of every button but the only way I could think of doing it was by looping to be able to have somewhat of an accurate touch feel and that idea just feels kind of sloppy.

Here is an example but the proportions for x and y are totally wrong, I'm just not sure how to compute it for a triangle:

```
    btnMove.addListener(new InputListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
            //this basically only cuts the image in half... I was thinking of cutting more from there
            //but I'm really not sure how to cut it exactly because of the triangle
            if(y > 38 && x > 22)
            {
                player.playerJump();
                return true;
            }
            else if(y < 38 && x < 22)
            {
                player.playerDodge;
                return true;
            }

          return false;
        }
    });
```

I have tried searching on the internet but I really can't find much so I would appreciate any ideas that I could implement.

By the way I almost forgot to mention I'm using scene2d in libGdx (if it wasn't clear).

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I know that there's probably too much text I'm just not really good at explaining my problems.

Comment: The "whole image" for one button sounds like the right approach.  Can you share some of the code that you came up with?  (i.e., the listener you registered with the button).  From a touch on the one button, you should be able to compute which quarter it landed in.

Comment: Ok I will add it, but my problem is I'm not sure how to compute it in a good way, I know how to get x and y and I'm able to use them but I'm not sure how to limit each button, because it's a triangle so I was thinking maybe I should loop to get the border or something but still not sure at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button image is effectively divided into four quadrants.  To compute which of the four quadrants a given point `x, y` are in, I think you just need to decide which side of each diagonal the point is on.  One diagonal is defined by where `x == y` (this is the diagonal from the bottom left to the top right).  Since the origin in the bottom left of this image, the diagonal from the top left to bottom is defined by `x == (WIDTH - y)`.  Now you just need figure out which side of each diagonal you're on:

```
boolean belowUpRight = (x > y);
boolean belowDownRight = (x < (WIDTH - y));
```

Now you can compute your four buttons by something like:

```
boolean touchLeft = !belowUpRight && belowDownRight;
boolean touchDown = belowUpRight && belowDownRight;
// etc ..
```

At least, in theory I think this works.  I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, I also found an even better one if someone else ever stumbles along this. There's a touchpad implementation in libgdx that can be used, you just have to set the knob as an empty image.

Comment: Heh, good point.  More details here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Touchpad.html